# Preferences layout is being overdrawn

Tags: android, android-layout

Has anybody seen anything like this?

I cannot find any reference, and LogCat does not give any indication.

This issue only started after I applied most of the Lint suggestions to my finished (so I thought) app. But I don't think that is the problem, because:

LDPI: 2.2.2 - problem

MDPI: 2.3.6 - problem

HDPI: (no test device)

XHDPI: 4.1.2 - no problem

===

My Preferences is within an old-skool TabActivity;

When you get there, it should look like this:

[image]

But if you wait 3-5 seconds, it becomes this;

[image]

See the stronger arrow graphic? Check out the text, too. This view has been overlayed; (with itself ??).

If I had spent a few seconds on the first, default, tab and then clicked to the Preferences tab, this is what I might expect to see:

[image]

The layout of the first tab (which is a @list) has overdrawn the Preferences.

I can't give any code examples, because no code has changed; it just happened.

Would be interested in any answers.

This is my Preference layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Sleep Setup" >
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:dialogTitle="Don&apos;t record sleep data if I press to wake within"
        android:entries="@array/sleepNullRecordName"
        android:entryValues="@array/sleepNullRecordValue"
        android:key="sleepNullRecord"
        android:summary="I press to wake within..."
        android:title="Ignore sleep data if" />

    <co.uk.FibroApp.customDialogs.PreferenceTimePickerDialog
        android:defaultValue="23:00"
        android:key="sleepPeriodStart"
        android:showDefault="true"
        android:summary="For charting / summaries"
        android:title="Usual sleep time" />
    <co.uk.FibroApp.customDialogs.PreferenceTimePickerDialog
        android:defaultValue="08:00"
        android:key="sleepPeriodEnd"
        android:showDefault="true"
        android:summary="For charting / summaries"
        android:title="Usual wake time" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Alarm" >
    <RingtonePreference
        android:key="prfRingtone"
        android:ringtoneType="alarm"
        android:showDefault="true"
        android:showSilent="true"
        android:summary="Pick a tone for your alarm"
        android:title="Alarm tone" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Phone Setup" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="chkAutoFlight"
        android:summary="Ignore calls whilst you sleep"
        android:title="Auto Flight Mode" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Reports" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:key="prfMyName"
        android:title="Your name" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue=""
        android:key="prfGPName"
        android:title="Your GP name" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: You say no code changed, but you applied fixes for lint warnings.  Something changed.  Start there and show the differences here.

Comment: Oh dear; that won't be possible as I applied the Lint fixes around a week ago and only caught this problem a couple of days after.

Comment: I do remember: my Lint fixes were only regarding Graphics and Layouts

Comment: I'm not disagreeing.  Just that we're not going to be able to help with the pictures alone.  Technically, if I answer with "No." can I get the check mark as your primary question is "have you seen anything like this?"  :P

Comment: I know. I've been sitting with this problem for a while, trying to decide how best to present my problem. I know I've got no code to show, or no warnings to pass on: that's why it is such a mystery

Comment: Show your layout XML.  That's the code you need to show.

Comment: I've added my Preference layout to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I don't know whether this was an effect of including the preferences activity within a TabActivity, but I found that if I commented out all of the preferences in the xml file, then the layout from the adjacent tab would appear as the background to the preference activity.

Without there being a 'background' xml element for a PreferenceScreen, I made a new theme with a black background and applied that theme to my preference activity in the Manifest.

Display problem solved.